# ruby error - invalid date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a date from DB in the following format - '1973-06-15'
When I try to create a date object with

```
dob = DateTime.strptime(user.date_of_birth.to_s, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I always get

```
invalid date
```

error. Outputting the date normally shows correct date. How to correctly parse dates in this case?

Comment: what is your data type of date_of_birth column?

Comment: Add output of `user.date_of_birth.to_s` to log and provide it here.

Comment: Works fine for me; what's the data type? What's `user.date_of_birth.to_s` returning?

Comment: I think `user.date_of_birth` contains `null` value.

Comment: It outputs 1973-06-15 and column type is DATE.

Comment: Then something else is wrong; here's my Rails console output: `1.9.3-p551 :003 > DateTime.strptime("1973-06-15", "%Y-%m-%d")
 => Fri, 15 Jun 1973 00:00:00 +0000`

Comment: whatever you are getting in user.date_of_birth is a date object so why you are making that value to string and then again to date object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that user.date_of_birth is a DateTime (or Date) object, you should be able to just do the following:

```
dob = user.date_of_birth.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: This gives me undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @Deez So... the date is `nil`. Use `try` or `andand`.

Comment: Like @DaveNewton said, then your date is nil. `user.try(:date_of_birth)` will prevent the error but you do need to discern why this method is returning `nil`.

Comment: Turns out that some entries were indeed nil and those caused the issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Glad it's sorted out :)!